# javascript validation issue for password

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

im having some issues concerning my javascript code for password. here's my code .that part is working fine, but i want to put another condition where my password should contains at least 8 characters and must abide the following rules : no spaces, contains at least 1 Uppercase and a number. concerning the mobile, it must always start with the no. 5 . help <3

```js
    function formValidation() {
 var mobile = document.forms["form"]["mobile"].value;
        var password = document.forms["form"]["password"].value;
       
//reg expression check
 var checkNumbers = /^[0-9 ]+$/;


$(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).focus(function(){
  $(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).css("background-color", "white");
 });
$(document.forms["form"]["password"]).focus(function(){
  $(document.forms["form"]["password"]).css("background-color", "white");
function clear(){
$(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).focus(function(){
  $(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).css("background-color", "white");
 });
$(document.forms["form"]["password"]).focus(function(){
  $(document.forms["form"]["password"]).css("background-color", "white");
 });
}

 if (mobile == null || mobile == "") {
        error[error.length]=("Enter your mobile number"); 
        document.form.mobile.focus();
        $(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).css("background-color", "blue");  
        ;         
    }else if (mobile != null || mobile != "") {
     if(!checkNumbers.test(mobile)){
     error[error.length]=("Enter Only numeric Characters for mobile phone");
  document.form.mobile.focus();
  $(document.forms["form"]["mobile"]).css("background-color", "blue");
     }
               
    }
        if (password == null || password == "") {
            error[error.length]=("Enter a password"); 
            document.form.password.focus();
            $(document.forms["form"]["password"]).css("background-color", "blue");   
        }

    }
```

```html
     
    <form name="form" onsubmit="return formValidation()" action="process.html">
    
Mobile phone:
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"></br></br>

Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></br></br>
    </form> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break it down into parts you can do this really easily and inform the user exactly which constraint they are failing, like this:

```
// Check the length:
if (password.length < 8) { // ... not long enough }

// Check if it has at least one upper case:
if (password.match(/[A-Z]+/g) === null) { // ... no upper case characters }

// Check if it has at least one number:
if (password.match(/\d/g) === null) { // ... no numbers }

// Password passes validation!
```

Comment: Hmm, I have it working at this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/4w6x0311/), can you try your inputs there?

Answer (score 0):

Test if all your conditions are met (`c1` condition 1 and so on)

```
var c1 = (password.toLowerCase() != password);// if it HAS uppercase letters, it won't match
var c2 = password.length > 8;
var c3 = !(password.indexOf(" ") > -1); // no spaces
var c4 = password.match(/\d+/g); // matches numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `RegExp` object and then pass in your password to its `test` method. The `RegExp` object can use positive lookaheads to assert that it finds an uppercase character and a digit character.

Finally, you can test that the password is at least 8 characters long and contains no white-space characters by attempting to pattern match at least 8 non-whitespace characters between the beginning-of-string token (^) and the end-of-string token ($). The pattern match will consume the entire string so if any whitespace characters are found, the test will fail, and if there are less than 8 characters, the test will also fail.

```
/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)^\S{8,}$/.test(password)
 ^uppercase ^digit  ^8+ characters in length and no whitespace
```

This expression will evaluate to true if the password is okay and false if not.